# Remove info window from an embedded Google map

Tags: html, css, google-maps

I'm trying to hide info window from Google embedded map. I was searching for solution, but can't find it anywhere.I want to hide info window and leave link for bigger map.

Link to map: http://dev01-www.erisata.lt/en.html#contacts

Any solutions for this?

Comment: It's not clear what are you looking for, so probably not easy to help you. Could you specify (maybe with an image about what do you refer by "info window from Google embedded map."

Answer (score 0):

You can't, but you can do a workaround for your case, by adding a new div with absolute position to hide the google map text content, replace your map-container div by :

```
<div class="map-container">
    <section style="background:#75716a; background: #e5e5e5;padding: 0;position:relative;">
        <iframe scrolling="no" width="100%" height="400" frameborder="0" style="border:0; -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); filter: grayscale(100%);" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d6522.283005371661!2d25.278750538590636!3d54.69246783787969!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x46dd941c3397b6eb%3A0x20df28c924221cdd!2zxaBlaW15bmnFoWtpxbMgZy4gMjMsIFZpbG5pdXMgMDkyMDA!5e0!3m2!1slt!2slt!4v1479197857183" allowfullscreen="" class=""></iframe>
        <div width="100%" style="left:0;right:0;position: absolute;bottom: 0px;background: #e5e5e5;">&nbsp;</div>
    </section>
</div>
```